# A testable invalid floating point value. (Floating point NULL)

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point

I want to be able to do the following:

```
float func()
{
    if( error ) return InvalidFloatingPointValue;
    else return 0.0f;
}

// somewhere else
float a = func();
if( a == InvalidFloatingPointValue )
    DoSomething();
```

Is there any reason I shouldn't do this?
Is there a cross-compiler, cross-platform(Windows, Linux, Android) value that can be used for such testing fast and safely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could return a NaN. This relies the return or the result of using the return in other expressions to be checked at some point, so should be documented.

```
#include <limits> // std::numeric_linits

float func()
{
  return  error ? std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN() : 0.0f;
}
```

With C++11 support, you can check whether the returned value is a NaN by using `std::isnan`. But you should not compare NaNs for equality: they comparison always yields `false`. The upside is that `a != a` is `true` if `a` is a NaN.

```
#include <cmath> // std::isnan, requires C++11

float a = func();
if(std::isnan(a)) DoSomething();
```

Comment: Note that testing NaNs for equality will not work as expected.  See `std::isnan()` in `<cmath>`.

Comment: An alternative for `isnan` is `if (a != a)`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `<double>::quiet_NaN` and not `<float>::quiet_NaN` ?

Comment: @akaltar I am sure I *don't* want to do that. Thanks for pointing out the mistake!

Comment: Actually the rules for NaN are designed so that in most cases, you do not need to test for NaN immediately. In most cases, you can let it propagate, perhaps through over operations that can produce NaN too, and test only once at the end. You may need to write your tests carefully (i.e. pay attention to the difference between  `x < y` and `!(x >= y)` )

Comment: That is true, but remember that many optimized (e.g. vectorized) math routines break down when dealing with NaNs. I've seen systems where propagating NaNs made everything run much slower (and hid where the NaNs came from).

Comment: @wnoise: It absolutely _will_ "work as expected", unless you failed to learn what NaNs are and how they work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `NaN` as  [@juanchopanza suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29194369/3848) but `NaN` can be subtle (`NaN == NaN` is `false`), also it's not clear to whoever reads the code that the returned value may have an invalid value.

I think a better fit for this problem is [`boost::optional<float>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

Usage:

```
boost::optional<float> func()
{
    if (error) 
        return boost::none;
    else
        return 0f;
}

// somewhere else
auto a = func();
if (!a)
    DoSomething();
else {
   // use *a
}
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it is worth mentioning it has an overhead.

Comment: @juanchopanza, true, very little overhead. I would suggest that the code clarity considerations trumps here.

Comment: Whether it is "little" or not really depends on the situation. It is worth pointing this out. For example, on my platform, an `optional<float>` is twice the size of a `float`.

Comment: @juanchopanza true (there's an extra `bool`) this is relevant if you store them but if they're passed by value it's negligible in all but the most performance intense applications. Don't forget [rules of optimization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/audiofool/archive/2007/06/14/the-rules-of-code-optimization.aspx).

Comment: I never understood why people find `!(NaN == NaN)` to be surprising. NaN isn't a number: it's, literally, _not a number_. How could it ever numerically compare equivalent to anything? This fact makes perfect intuitive sense!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well sorta when you use explicit `NaN`. But if you're using a variable then most people don't consider the `NaN` option and would be very surprised to find `a != a` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @Motti: *shrug* I don't get it. Those are silly people.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I disagree, most of peoples' experience with floating point numbers are for `FP_NORMAL` values. When they see a floating point number it takes an extra effort to consider `NaN` `+-Inf` and `-0`. Just like when treating signed numbers people would assume that if `n` is negative then `-n` is positive. This isn't stupidity, it's our responsibility to reduce the chance of error by removing the edge cases as much as possible (that's why I think `optional<float>` is better than `NaN` here).

Comment: @Motti: Nobody said it's stupidity. Honestly, though, the "effort" involved is truly marginal. I put it down to poor education.

Answer (score 1):

Using an exception is probably better instead. Alternatively you can use a `bool` return value type, and a `float&` reference (out) parameter.